# How can I match the wall color after dent fixing?

Tags: walls, paint, repainting

I used to have a couple of small dents in one of my walls (the walls are plastered brick if that matters). I covered them and the wall is now smooth. However the main issue I have right now is the paint. Is there any way to paint the fixed areas without painting the whole wall and without having a noticeable difference between the old wall color and these fixed patches?
First I thought about trying to match the original color but there are 2 problems with that:

1. I didn't paint the wall in the first place and finding the exact color will be impossible.
2. I assume that since the wall paint is fairly old, even if I find the exact color, it is still going to be different from fresh paint.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best shot at that would have been to take a large enough chip from the damaged portion of the wall before it was repaired, take it to a paint store to have it computer color matched. There would have been only a chance it would been an exact match still.

Your next best bet if it is close enough, is to paint the wall corner to corner, at least it would not be the whole room.

Comment: Exactly what I do with drywall. I use a utility knife to cut a 1" square of paper out, peeling it away from the gyp inside. Hit the hole with a bit of mud and head to the store.